# Publishing short fiction stories?

Tags: fiction, publishing, self-publishing, journalism, publisher

I have recently written a couple of short fiction stories and I would like to get them published. My searches on the internet has left me dazzled. There are so many option and most of them are just not what I'm looking for. Do you know a place where they publish short fiction or poetry?  I'm not looking for a journal/magazine that you need to pay to get considered for publication or one where you have to wait for months to get a reply. I'm even thinking of starting my own journal/magazine for people just like me.

Comment: When you say 'get them published' what exactly do you mean? For example, you could just set up your own website and publish them there. What are you not looking for other than having to pay or waiting? Are you thinking about something like Kindle books? Do you have the skills/expertise/time to set up a website? I think answers will be more useful if you can clear up one or two of these issues.

Comment: Somehow I always think that a person who writes something also reads the same thing. I write novels because I read novels. So I know where novels are published: all I have to do is open the books I read and look at the publisher information. I submit to the same publishers that publish the books I love. You write short stories. I would think that you write short stories because you read short stories. So you know where short stories are published: all you have to do is open the anthologies, magazines, or website about pages and look at the publisher information. Submit there.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention having any other writing experience or what you may have done in terms of edits, etc., so my comments are assuming these are your first stories. Just because you've written some stories, it does not mean they are ready for publication. You may have great stuff there (evaluate them against some of the favorites that you've read) or they might not be ready for prime time yet. You may want to try workshopping them through a site like Scribophile.com, which is a good place to give and get critiques, or with a local writers' group. Making sure your writing is the best it can be will make the process of submitting to journals less painful, because you are more likely to be accepted.

If/when the stories are ready to send out, in addition to @what's suggestion about looking at the magazines you read, you can also take a look at Duotrope.com. They have a database you can search and links to the different journals so you can check the individual magazine's submission guidelines. Always follow the guidelines or the odds are your stuff will get tossed. Duotrope usually gives an indication of how long it takes to get a response (I can't remember, you may have to subscribe to get those statistics.)

Good luck. Keep writing. Work the craft.

Answer (score -1):

"I'm even thinking of starting my own journal/magazine for people just like me."

Many journals make serious efforts to be respectable towards their contributors. They don't WANT to make you wait long, they just don't have the funding or time to answer everybody in a timely manner, let alone with good news.

Start your journal, and you'll see. You get a thousand entries in a week, at say an average word count of 3,000 words. That's 3 million words in a week. Good luck.

Comment: I found this very unclear. Are you saying journals do or do not make you wait long? Are you suggesting OP actually start a journal as a solution, or are you pointing out that starting a journal is much more difficult than OP may think? Does this actually answer the question of where to publish? It doesn't seem to.